adding multi-geo sharepoint site resource to catalog using v1.0 Power Shell commands
we are using the PowerShell SDK to provision catalog in entitlement management and add a SharePoint Online site as a resource. We found there are a few articles that the entitlement management supports Multi-Geo. Here is the article from Microsoft: Multi-geo add resource to catalog.
When I am using the command New-MgEntitlementManagementResourceRequest and use url parameter as japan region provisioned site, it just fails to add.
$params = @{ requestType = "adminAdd" resource = @{ displayName = $requestObj.requestTitle description = $requestObj.requestTitle originId ="https://companyjpn.sharepoint.com/teams/testjapan" originSystem = "SharePointOnline" } catalog = @{ id = $catalogObj.Id } } New-MgEntitlementManagementResourceRequest -BodyParameter $params | Out-Null -ErrorAction Stop ERROR: [RequestFailedInOriginSystem] : "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.","details" New-MgEntitlementManagementResourceRequest_Create: Line | 910 | New-MgEntitlementManagementResourceRequest -BodyParameter $pa … | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ | "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.","details" Status: 400 (BadRequest) ErrorCode: RequestFailedInOriginSystem Date: 2024-12-26T11:58:25
Anyone please help in adding multi-geo site as a resource in the catalog? Thanks
How to reproduce
$params = @{ requestType = "adminAdd" resource = @{ originId = "https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/sites/Example" originSystem = "SharePointOnline" } catalog = @{ id = "beedadfe-01d5-4025-910b-84abb9369997" } }
New-MgEntitlementManagementResourceRequest -BodyParameter $params
Expected behavior
HTTP/1.1 201 Created Content-type: application/json
{ "id": "acc2294e-f37f-42d3-981d-4e83847ed0ce", "requestType": "adminAdd", "state": "delivered" }
